# Disabling validation in a particular case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my `User` model I set validations for the password and its confirmation:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation
```

I use this for the forms. These attributes are not stored in the database, I am using the `authlogic` gem.

Now I am trying to make a system to restore forgotten passwords via email. The user inputs his email and the object is retrieved like this:

```
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Then, at a certain point in the process the value of a `User` attribute is set to `true` meaning that the user forgot his password, so I need to do a `@user.save`.

And there's the problem. Since `password` and `password_confirmation` were never stored, their values are `nil`. However, the validations come in play and prevent the user from being updated.

Is there any way to skip those particular validations so I can make this work? Or should I do something else? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip all validations with `save(validate: false)`. You can skip individual validations with the `:if` or `:unless` option, for example.

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, unless: :forgot_password?

def forgot_password?
  # return true if the user is in the forgot password process
end
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation
```

to

Assuming your field that is set to `true` is `forgot_password`

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, :unless =>  Proc.new { |a| a.forgot_password? }
```

Conditional Validations [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)